# How to get functions inside functions to get their data before the function returns?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
export const getTagsByType = <Data extends { keywords?: { tags: { name: string, type: string }[] } }>(type: string, rawData: Data) => {
    return rawData.keywords?.tags.filter((tag) => tag.type === type).map(tag => tag.name);
}


export const buildLoadedData = () => {
    const rawDTMData = window.DATA;

    return {
        "loaded_content":getTagsByType("generic", rawDTMData).toString(),
        
    }
}
```

However, `buildLoadedData` returns before the function executes for some reason. What do I do here so that loaded_content actually has some content?

Comment: my guess is that is not your exact code or `window.DATA` does not have what you think it has at that moment in time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @devlincarnate There is no async call in that code.

Comment: @epascarello - but isn't the solution the same to what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @devlincarnate The problem is not in the code the OP shared. There is not a single async call in it.

Comment: @epascarello - but if the linked duplicate provides a solution to the OP's question, it's a valid duplicate. There is no requirement that the questions themselves are the same. The OP needs to have a function wait for another function to return. That duplicate provides a solution for what the OP needs.

Comment: @devlincarnate WHERE is the asynchronous code in OPs code. Where? :) I would agree with you if there was asynchronous code, but filter and map is not async. The problem is not in the code that is provided.